# Have two servlet contexts in one Spring Boot application context under Jetty

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, jetty

Imagine I have one Spring Boot instance, pretty boring, one ApplicationContext, starter-jetty. By default, it does one ServletContext on /, puts a DispatcherServlet on / too. Every servlet and filter then placed under this context.

Now, I want to have one servlet context with contextPath=/api with a few servlets and another servlet context under /internal with a different set of servlets. They have to share ApplicationContext and most beans. And yes, it has to be plain old servlets & filters, not just two WebMvc instances.

How do I configure that? The most crucial question is how to make two ServletContext's for Jetty to consume. Just class names are enough, links to examples are encouraged. Hints on how to painlessly configure the distribution of Servlet's and Filter's between servlet contexts are appreciated too.